# replace blank or whitespace to zero

Tags: python

I certainly think that there are similar questions like this, so really sorry.

I have a list with blank.

```
a = ['','3']
```

how can I change this list to

```
['0','3']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

list comprehension:

```
r = ['0' if i == "" else i for i in a]
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this

```
a = [0 if x == '' else x for x in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

change manually in-place

```py
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i] == '':
        l[i] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```py
b = ['0' if len(x) == 0 else x for x in a]
print(b)
```

The output is:

```
['0', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array is already initiated. You could do:

```
index = 0
for Element in a:
    if Element == "" or Element == " ":
         a[index] = "0"
    index = index + 1
```

You could shorter the code pretty easily but its an overview.